# why Apache is not started in xampp server?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am using windows 7 and my xampp version is 5.5.28 and this is the error message in control panel :
Initializing Control Panel
11:45:04  [main]    Windows Version: Windows 7 Ultimate  32-bit
11:45:04  [main]    XAMPP Version: 5.5.28
11:45:04  [main]    Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
11:45:04  [main]    You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
11:45:04  [main]    most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
11:45:04  [main]    there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
11:45:04  [main]    about running this application with administrator rights!
11:45:04  [main]    XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
11:45:04  [main]    Checking for prerequisites
11:45:05  [main]    All prerequisites found
11:45:05  [main]    Initializing Modules
11:45:05  [Apache]  Problem detected!
11:45:05  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4056!
11:45:05  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
11:45:05  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
11:45:05  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
11:45:05  [Apache]  Problem detected!
11:45:05  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4056!
11:45:05  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
11:45:05  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
11:45:05  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
11:45:05  [main]    Starting Check-Timer
11:45:05  [main]    Control Panel Ready
11:55:39  [Apache]  Problem detected!
11:55:39  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4056!
11:55:39  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
11:55:39  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
11:55:39  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
11:55:39  [Apache]  Problem detected!
11:55:39  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4056!
11:55:39  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
11:55:39  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
11:55:39  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
11:55:39  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
11:55:40  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
11:55:41  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
11:55:41  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
11:55:41  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:55:41  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:55:41  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:55:41  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:55:41  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
11:55:41  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

Comment: It seems your port 80 is in use by some other software. Try changing the apache port in httpd.conf. Change this line Listen 80 to something like Listen 8080.

Comment: ok,,,I changed the port from httpd.conf file but still its not working.But what about ssl port,,,how can I change it?

Comment: EasyPhp software is already installed in my computer but I dont have skypee.....Does the EasyPhp cause this problem?